# Trying find a better writing for my SQL Query

Tags: sql

I Have a database of published website pages, with following coulmns:

`date| publisher_id | platform | page_views`

The platform is the platform the page was showed on (Mobile OR Desktop)

I need to write an SQL query that will meet the following requirement:

For every publisher that has mobile traffic (publisher can publish only at desktop, only at mobile or both), find that publisher’s total amount of page views across all platforms.

I tried the next steps:

1. Create a new column - `case when "platform"='Mobile' then 1 else 0 end user_has_mobile_traffic`
2. Make the table as Sub-Query, and then group the rows by publisher_id and indictor if he has mobile_traffic
3. Then I got a list of all the publishers that have mobile traffic
4. At the original table, If the publisher_id IN the list i've made then sum page_views

What do you think? Is there any easier way, or my way is good enough?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to show the definitions of the database tables (along with any indexes), and the database type you're using.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It really hard to answer your questions without any more details. I would recommend that you add the DDL for the table itself and then the statements to insert some data. The easier you make for someone trying to help to recreate a sample of your dataset the faster you'll get a helpful answer. Please consider re-writing your question with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without the `IN (<sub-query>)`, reducing the number of times you scan the table, just by using a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT
  publisher_id,
  SUM(page_views)
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY
  publisher_id
HAVING
  MAX(CASE WHEN platform = 'Mobile' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```